# how to pass Auth Token from login window to app window in electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I created an app in electron with react. I made two windows: `login window` and `app window`. In the login window, I set up a basic HTML form and I call the login endpoint from being like this:

```
async function login() {
  const response = await loginResponse(
    usernameInput.value,
    passwordInput.value
  );
  if (response?.invalidData === true) {
    alert("Wrong credentials!");
    return;
  }
  return ipcRenderer.send("open-app", response?.token, response?.displayName);
}
```

The event open-app it's for creating an app window and sending a token, displayName to react app:

```
ipcMain.on("open-app", async (e, token, displayName) => {
    console.log(token, displayName);
    if (appWindow) {
      appWindow.focus();
      return;
    }
    appWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1200,
      height: 900,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
        enableRemoteModule: true,
      },
    });

    appWindow.webContents.on("dom-ready", (e) => {
      appWindow.webContents.send("auth-data", {
        token,
        displayName,
      });
    });

    appWindow.loadURL(
      isDev
        ? "http://localhost:3000"
        : `file://${__dirname}/../build/index.html`
    );
});
```

And in my App.js I save token in local storage:

```
useEffect(() => {
    ipcRenderer.on("auth-data", async (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      const { token, displayName } = data;
      console.log(token);
      if (token && displayName) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("auth", token);
        window.localStorage.setItem("displayName", displayName);
        await apiService.markOnline(token);
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

the problem it's the token doesn't save or if it's saved it doesn't update in localstorage when I re-open the app. How to send and update properly the token between the windows?

Comment: Does the last function run? Do you see the console logs?

Comment: no, I don't see console logs

Comment: Right, my guess is that you're sending the `auth-data` message too early, before you've set up your React code to receive it. I'd 1. store the data in server vars 2. open the app window 3. let your React app load the data instead of receiving it - You can use this: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-2-renderer-to-main-two-way

Comment: can you show me how to synchronize the event?

Comment: The page I linked you to explains in detail how to 1. invoke an event 2. handle it in the main process 3. send data back to the renderer

Comment: @CosminCiolacu How are you going with this? How about this, instead of awaiting your `loginResponse` in your render thread, can you place this in your main thread? IE: Send your login forms `username` and `password` to your main thread for processing. If successful, re-focus the app window and kill the login window. You will then have the login credentials already there to pass on to the main window. If login is unsuccessful, then send a message to the login window indicating so. This will separate concerns a little more and leave the heavy lifting of the login API to the main thread.